# Three js vertex edge colors are spread on nearby vertex color, How to stop color spreading here?

Tags: angular, colors, three.js

Created a buffer geometry with polygons normals and colors along with mesh lambert material like this below

```
geometry.setAttribute( 'position', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute( positions, 3 ));geometry.setAttribute( 'normal', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute( normals, 3 ));geometry.setAttribute( 'color', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute( colors, 3 ));
```

```
const material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( {color: 0xd5d5d5, vertexColors: true, side: THREE.DoubleSide} );
```

```
const mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
```

But using multiple colors are not looking sharp edges instead it is highlighted in edges of triangle and looking like stars smudging with nearby color. How to stop that highlighted borders? Needs only that color maps not highlighted triangle borders.

Sample Output:
[Click to view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnxJe.png)